# Error during Sonar Scanner execution running Tibco project

Tags: sonarqube, tibco, sonarscanner

Must-share information (formatted with [Markdown](https://commonmark.org/help/)):
SonarQube (9.5.0.56709), Scanner (4.7.0.2747) Tibco project
Hello, When running Sonar on the latest accessible version (9.5) with Sonar Scanner version (4.7), I encountered the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6V84.png)

As we can see in the image, this happens when the CheckRules are being validated.

In highlight we see that the error is caused by the fact that the execution is set with the initial interval equal to the final one (12,97). In previous versions of Sonar this was not a problem

I have tried many searches in the web and came up empty, this is basicly my last resource.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp8FG.png)
I managed this workAround but obviously this cant stay like this.

My gratitude in advance for your time and sugestions

Comment: Please embed the screenshots into the post

Comment: Sorry I cant, because I need 10 of reputation